# React HOC Nesting within Nested Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have two different lines of code, I've found one that works, but I don't know why. I'd like some insight to React internals to understand the mechanics behind what is going on.

Here's some context. I have a nested navigator, and I'm implementing a goBack functionality. The goBack functionality necessarily needs to go back in the *nested* navigator, not the *root* navigator. For example, if my navigation history is RootA -> NestedA -> NestedB...then going back should go to NestedA, *not* RootA.

In order to follow DRY principles, I made the goBack functionality a HOC wrapper. This is what it looks like:

```
export const withBack = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

      return (props) => {
          return <>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: 1, }}>
                <Appbar.Header style={{ backgroundColor: colors.onSurface, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                    <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} color='black'/>
                </Appbar.Header>
            </SafeAreaView>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.onSurface}}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} />
            </SafeAreaView>
          </>;
        
      }
    }
```

I am using it in my nested stack navigator like this:

```
          <Stack.Screen name="Branches"
          component={withBack((props) => <Branches {...props} />)} />
```

However, doing so causes the back button to go back in *root* navigator, not the nested one.

Doing this instead gets the desired behavior:

```
          <Stack.Screen name="Branches"
          component={()=> withBack((props) => <Branches {...props} />)()} />
```

Can anyone explain to me why these two result in different behavior?

Comment: The docs say that the `useNavigation` returns the navigation prop for the screen its inside. So I  guess that in the first version, `withBack` is immediately called and navigation is scoped to the root navigator. I guess nesting the function stops the immediate calling of `withBack`. I would say that nesting `withBack` in a function makes it loses the root navigator scope; but if it did then props would be lost; so I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Try using `navigation.pop()` instead of `navigation.goBack()`

Comment: @PhantomSpooks it could be! putting it inside the closure could be delaying the execution of `withBack` which delays the execution of `useNavigation`, which by that time the nested `NavigationContainer` would have mounted, so `useNavigation` returns the correct navigator.